# How to use jCarousel to enlarge a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have implemented jcarousel.

My website looks like this: [what my website looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub8Pl.jpg)

What I want to do, is that when the user clicks on enlarge, I want the picture to open in a new tab and have it be a slider as well. Basically I want to open the slider in a new tab when the enlarge image is clicked.

Im new to this, I'm not sure what to do or where to start. All i have done is place the code below on the enlarge image. Please advise me on what to do?

```
<a href="javascript:enlarge()" class="enlarge">
<img src="/theme/images/magnify.gif" border="0" title="enlarge" alt="enlarge" style="margin:;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use some "js modal gallery" it have enlarge effect and dont need open new tab

Answer (score 0):

in short adding target to an anchor will open it in a new tab,

```
<a href="#" target="blank"></a>
```

The long answer is I have no idea what you're needing to execute when the new page is loaded, that is something that is going to be beyond this initial question.